# Citation hyperlinks stop working if section is added

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, citing, biber

I am using a `.cls` file to style my document, and have unfortunately run into a rather uncommon problem.

I am using a `.bib` file to add citations, and `\printbibliography` to print the bibliography. When I start with the document and cite within a chapter (no sections or subsections added yet), the citation hyperlink jumps to the bibliography page (as expected).

**However, as soon as I add a section, even if I don't cite anything in the section, the citation hyperlink stops working and redirects to the top of the document (1st page).**

I am using the `\cite` function with the keyword from the `.bib` file to cite.

```latex
\documentclass[index,index=totoc,bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc,english]{Class_Name_Here}

\usepackage[withpage]{acronym} % Abkürzungsverzeichnis
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes} % für Zitation
\usepackage[binary-units=true,per-mode=symbol,decimalsymbol=comma]{siunitx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic, refsection=section]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\addbibresource{Sources.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\label{chap:intro}

Text text text \cite{sourcename}. % works fine until section added

\chapter{Fundamentals}
\label{chap:funda}

Text text text

\section{First section}
\label{sec:firstsec} % citation hyperlink breaks as soon as these two lines added

\end{document}
```

With a following sample `Sources.bib` file:

```
@misc{sourcename,
    Author = {{authorname}},
    Date-Added = {2016-11-10},
    Date-Modified = {2017-06-05},
    Howpublished = {\url{https://www.google.com/}},
    Title = {Google},
    note = {Accessed: 2020-08-13}}
```

Comment: you will have to make a complete, small example.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have modified the question to include as much detail as I am allowed to. Unfortunately I cannot include the details of the class and it has been replaced with a placeholder name ```{Class_Name_Here}```.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but with `biblatex` it is a much better idea to use the dedicated fields `url` and `urldate` for the URL and access date instead of the generic `Howpublished` and `note`. Replace `Howpublished = {\url{https://www.google.com/}}, note = {Accessed: 2020-08-13}` with `url = {https://www.google.com/}, urldate = {2020-08-13},`. (There is also a type `@online` instead of `@misc`)

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I will change my ```.bib``` file accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You load `biblatex` with `refsection=section` which essentially creates a new, separate bibliography environment for each `\section`.

If you don't have a `\printbibliography` for that section, the citations will essentially be left hanging without a suitable bibliography. This can be seen by wrong link targets but may also mean that citations don't appear in the bibliography at all.

You don't see any adverse effects if you don't have any `\section` commands.

---

If you only want one global bibliography at the end of your document, remove the option `refsection=section`.

If you want to have a separate bibliography for each chapter, load `biblatex` with the option `refsection=chapter,` and add a

```
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
```

in *each* `\chapter`.

The same strategy is also possible if you want a separate bibliography for each section, though that probably goes too far.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am an utter LaTeX novice and had just accepted all the usepackage statements as given.

Comment: @Rohan Ah, one of the most important lessons in learning LaTeX is never to trust code you were just given by someone else. Especially if it's a large 'thesis template'. (Some of these are apparently passed down through generations of students and amass a huge load of outdated, sometimes bad or at least questionable code.)